# How to count value of foreach loop?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, foreach

I'm creating my first laravel project and i want to get info from 'nutrition' sql table and count results for each user. I'm output'ing my 'users' table ant my ***.blade.php (theme file) using foreach. I want to do something that counts value for each user.

My function inside controller:

```
public function nutrition() {
       $id = Auth::User() -> id;
        $users = DB::SELECT('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE tr_id = ?', ["$id"]);
        return view('mitybos-valdymas', compact('users'));
}
```

My route:
`Route::get('/mityba', 'HomeController@nutrition');`

Inside ***.blade.php

```
  @foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }}
  @endforeach
```

Example what i want to do in laravel (not php):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE tr_id = 1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {  
      $u_id = $row['id'];  
      $name = $row['name'];  
      $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM nutrition WHERE user = '$u_id'");  
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql2);    
      echo "User name - " . $name. " / RESULT - " . $count;   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `{{ $loop->index }}` or `{{ $loop->iteration }}` inside @foreach.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
  {{ $loop->index }}     // start with 0
  {{ $loop->iteration }} // start with 1
  {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
```

For more info. You can check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable) https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: This is an efficient way of counting loops inside the blade.

Answer (score 4):

This is another way to do it, so it will start from 0 till the number of users

```
 @foreach ($users as $index => $user)
   {{ $index }}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: This is a poor solution as it assumes that `$users` array was populated with auto generated keys and that no array items were removed in the processing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72512807/352040) rather.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would create a `Nutrition` [Eloquent model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) and use Laravel's [relationship functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships). But if you can't / don't want to, then create your own.

```
    // In app/User.php
    public function nutritions()
    {
        return DB::table('nutrition')->where('user',$this->id);
    }
```

Then:

```
    // In blade view
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        {{ $user->nutritions()->count() }}
    @endforeach
```

PS you can use the `DB` facade's methods for selecting like I did above, rather than writing out raw queries.

If you fix up your tables and use Eloquent for `Nutrition` then it would be as simple as this:

```
    // In app/User.php
    public function nutritions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Nutrition','user');
    }
```

Note that if you go the Eloquent route it would be worth changing your DB schema to use the Laravel naming convention, e.g. your `User`s should be stored in a table called `users` and your `nutrition` table would become `nutritions` with `user_id` as the foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Use {{$loop->count}} it will give the total count of foreach loop

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$loop->count}} //for total count
{{$loop->iteration}} // for index but start with 1
{{$loop->index}} // for index start with 0
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, if I have perfectly understood your question :)

**//Route**

```
Route::get('/mityba', 'HomeController@nutrition');
```

**//Homecontroller@nutrition**

```
public function nutrition() {
     $authId = Auth::id();
     $users = DB::table('clients')->where('tr_id', $authId)->get(); //sql1
     return view('mitybos-valdymas', compact('users'));
}
```

**//inside of mitybos-valdymas.blade.php**, 
Check this link [use PHP in the Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#php)

```
@php
  $count = 0; //Initialize variable
@endphp
@foreach ($users as $user)
  $count += 1;
  $result = DB::table('nutrition')->where('user', $user->id)->get() //sql2
  echo "User name - " . $result->name. " / RESULT - " . $count;   
@endforeach
```

For your peace in the coding :)

Comment: The coding here is poor (e.g. `$count += 1;` vs. `$count++;`) and there is too much logic in the view. You definitely shouldn't be using `echo` in a blade template.

Comment: @lufc If it is intended to make it easier to give understand, this level of acceptance is acceptable, what is too much?:p always forced to use MVC make another restrict to coding. and minor performance improvements are possible after a complete understanding.